# Evaluate the determinant of a matrix and determine those values of t for which the determinant of the matrix is zero

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

The purpose of this question is to fully understand how to answer the following question and show the full working on paper without the aid of a computer. (Note that I am refreshing my Linear Algebra knowledge).

Question - Evaluate the determinate |A| of

A = $\begin{bmatrix}t-2 & 4 & 3\\ 1 & t+1 & -2\\0 & 0 & t-4 \end{bmatrix}$

Determine those values of t for which |A| = 0.

**My Approach:**

**step 1 - Calculate the minors for row 3**

Note I am only using M${_3,_3}$ because A ${_3,_1}$ & A${_3,_2}$ both have value of zero.

M${_3,_3}\begin{bmatrix}t-2 & 4\\1 & t+1\\\end{bmatrix}$

$\therefore$ the cofactor value will be derived from:

(-1)$^{3 + 3}$((t - 2 ${\times}$ t + 1) - (4 ${\times}$ 1)) = -t - 3

$\therefore$ |A| = (t - 4) ${\times}$ (-t - 3) = -t$^2$ + t + 12

**Questions**

1. Is the above correct so far?
2. Having evaluated the determinant I now need to determine those values of t for which |A| is zero.

**My approach for 2:**

Use the formula:   ax$^3$ + bx$^2$ + cx + d

I insert -t$^2$ + t + 12

such that : x$^3$ - x$^2$ + x + 12 = 0

Then solve.

Is this the correct approach to this problem and how would I solve on paper?

Comment: Your idea of looking at the minors is good. It simplifies things a lot. From then on you messed up the arithmetic. You can't end up with a negative coefficient on $t^2$ here, plus the $t^3$ term is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
|A|&=& \left| \begin{matrix}t-2 & 4 & 3\\ 1 & t+1 & -2\\0 & 0 & t-4 \end{matrix}\right| \\
&=& (t-4)\times \left| \begin{matrix}t-2 & 4 \\ 1 & t+1\end{matrix}\right| \\
&=& (t-4)\left[(t-2)(t+1)-4\times 1 \right]\\
&=& (t-4) \left[t^2+t-2t-2-4 \right]\\
&=& (t-4)\left[t^2-t-6 \right]\\
&=& (t-4)(t+2)(t-3)\\
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Are you able to explain the workings line by line?  I am very rusty and want to completely understand this.

Comment: I am doing the same calculation as you @toasteez